# Calculus - Find the position and velocity of an object when it hits the ground - using vector

Tags: calculus, vectors, projectile-motion

If an object is thrown in the air with an initial position of $(0,0,4)$ in feet and initial velocity $(200,0,256)$ in feet per second, and the acceleration is $(0,8,-32)$. Find the position and velocity of an object when it hits the ground.

**My attempt**

Tangential Component:

$ \frac{\langle(200,0,256),\,(0,8,-32)\rangle}{\|(200,0,256)\|}$ = $\frac{-8192}{8\sqrt{1649}}$

Normal Component:

$ \frac{\|(2048,6400,1600)\|}{\|(200,0,256)\|}$ = $\frac{64\sqrt{11649}}{8\sqrt{1649}}$

Comment: After having plugged numbers into a couple of formulas, what were you planning to do with the resulting values?

Answer (score 1):

Your tangential has $\vec {v_0}\cdot \vec a$ which doesn't make sense and I don't know where $\langle 2048,6400,1600 \rangle$ comes from in the normal.  I would just use $\vec s=\vec{s_0}+\vec {v_0}t+\frac 12\vec a t^2$  You are given the constants on the right.  Solve for $t$ that makes the height (presumably the third component) zero, then plug that in to get the first two.

Comment: <2048,6400,1600> comes from the cross product of Vo to Ao a.k.a |VoxAo|

Comment: so If I use  s =s0+v0t+1/2at^2 it will be s= <0,0,4> + <200,0,256>t + 1/2<0,8,-32>t^2 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.